# parse an XML to a Stringarray

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-xmlpullparser

I'm looking for help to get an XML to an arraylist.

here is the XML :

```
<campagne>
  <sms><texte>
          Vente a Drouot
    </texte>
  <list>
    <id> 1 </id>
      <nom> TOTO </nom>
    <id> 2 </id>
      <nom> TATA </nom>
    <id> 3 </id>
      <nom> Mr.Gerard </nom>
   </list>
</sms>
</campagne>
```

I want to have TOTO,TATA,Mr.Gerard to a StringArray[] exactly like if I put manually : String[] Customers = {"TOTO","TATA","Mr.Gerard"}

for now my XMlPullParser (I have written " ArrayList clientslist = null; " before and I want to put the difference name in this Array )
:

```
public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        String text = null;
ArrayList<Client> clientslist = null;

        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = myParser.getName();

                switch (event) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (name.equals("texte"))
                        message = text.trim();

                    else if (name.equals("nom")) 
                        clientslist = text.trim(); // error is here

                    else 

                    break;
                }
                event = myParser.next();

            }
            parsingComplete = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

With this code I have Mr.Gerard ONLY...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `clients` is a `String` - it should be a `List<String>` instead and `clients = text.trim();` should be replaced with `clients.add(text.trim());`

Then you can call `clients.toArray(new String[clients.size()])` to get a String array you wanted.

Comment: sorry I forgot to said that i put  ArrayList<Client> clientslist = null;
 before the whole code i posted, so i replace client to clients(which is an array) and it makes an error i have to change to string)

Comment: Ok. Replace `clients = text.trim();` with `clientslist.add(new Client(text.trim()));` to populate `clientslist`. Then you can read from `clientslist ` as `List` or get an array of it's values via `clientslist.toArray(new Client[clientslist.size()])`

Comment: P.S. And dont initialise with null. Have `List<Client> clientslist = new ArrayList<Client>();` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What is the `clients` member variable?  Without seeing the rest of the code it appears that you are simply over-writing it with whatever happens to be the last `<nom>` element.

Use a List and add each `<nom>` to that and then convert the list to a string array.

Answer (score 0):

Use index for the string array to update the values.

```
public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        int counter = 0;
        String text = null;
        String[] clients = {};

        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = myParser.getName();

                switch (event) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (name.equals("texte"))
                        message = text.trim();

                    else if (name.equals("nom")) 
                        clients[counter++] = text.trim();

                    else 

                    break;
                }
                event = myParser.next();

            }
            parsingComplete = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        ArrayList<String> clientslist = new ArrayList<String>;       // 1
                  ...
                    else if (name.equals("nom")){
                        clients = text.trim();
                        clientslist.add(text.trim());     //2
                    }
                    ...
        return clientslist;    //3
    }
```

at the end , you can get the list